# I want to click 2 buttons sequentially in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

The site I use has 2 download buttons, PNG and PSD.
[Image of 2 download buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74V6v.png)

Currently I just clicked the PSD button to get the download link.Because when clicking the button it doesn't open a new tab but uses the current tab.

I want to press 2 JPG and PSD buttons at the same time to get the download link in the input box of each tab.

Soucre sample code of a file on the site I make: [view-source:https://lovepik.com/image-401238137/graduation.html](https://view-source:https://lovepik.com/image-401238137/graduation.html)

This is the code I got the download link at the PSD button:

```
                 try:
                    psd = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="pub jpg_psd"]//*[@class="pub_s psd_s"]')

                    # jpg = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="pub jpg_psd"]//*[@class="pub_s jpg_s"]')

                    if psd.is_displayed():
                        psd.click()
                        print("Here is a link with 2 buttons")
                 except NoSuchElementException:
                       print("Couldn't find any elements")
                       content = "The link you entered is incorrect. Please check again."
                       return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form, 'link': content})

             time.sleep(2)

             driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

             print(driver.current_url)

             try:
                close_download = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="btn_close act_lazy"]')
                if close_download.is_displayed():
                   close_download.click()
                   print("Element appears")
             except NoSuchElementException:
                print("Element not found")

          time.sleep(2)

          content = driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, '//input[@class="copy-ipt link"]').get_attribute("value")

          print("Link download is: ", content)

          driver.quit()
          return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form, 'link': content})
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking at the same time will not work.
The best alternative is, instead of clicking, just opening the PSD or PNG in a new tab using the href that the download is linked to. In your case, it is a bit more difficult, since they do not use a direct href, but the env.allowDownload(...). You can still use the same method, however, and use JavaScriptExecutor from Selenium.

```js
driver.execute_script("env.allowDownload(...)");
```

This way, you can download both files while still remaining on the same webpage.

Good luck!

Comment: I followed the instructions and got 1 link successfully:

png = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@class="pub_s jpg_s"]').get_attribute("onclick")
                            print("URL env.allowDownload: ", png)
                            abc = driver.execute_script(png)
                            print("Link Download : ", abc)


However I still only get 1 link because the browser doesn't open a new tab. What should I do